# Midrule before a not empty cell with pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

Is it possible with `pgfplotstable` to check if a cell is not empty and put a `\midrule` before this row?

For example I have the names of a sample in the first column and before every new sample I want a `\midrule`. If every sample has the same amount of rows I could use the `every nth row` option of `pgfplotstable`.

But how can I solve this, if the amount of rows per sample is not the same?
Here a MWE which illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}

\begin{filecontents}{dataC.csv}
Name,    pH,     concentration
Sample 1,   1.01,      1.52
    ,   1.00,   1.51
    ,   1.02,   1.53
Sample 2,   2.01,      -1.52
    ,   2.00,   -1.51
    ,   2.02,   -1.53
Sample 3,   3.01,      -2.52
    ,   3.00,   -2.51
Sample 4,   4.01,      -3.52
    ,   4.00,   -3.51
    ,   4.02,   -4.53
    ,   4.01,   -3.51
    ,   4.03,   -3.54
Sample 5,   5.01,      -4.52
    ,   5.00,   -4.51
    ,   5.02,   -4.53
\end{filecontents}    

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={Name, pH, concentration}, 
    fixed zerofill, 
    columns/Name/.style={string type,},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    every nth row={3}{before row=\midrule},
    ]{dataC.csv}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `every row no <index>`. It affords manual counting of the rows and adding the style for each affected row again, but…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}

\begin{filecontents}{dataC.csv}
Name,    pH,     concentration
Sample 1,   1.01,      1.52
    ,   1.00,   1.51
    ,   1.02,   1.53
Sample 2,   2.01,      -1.52
    ,   2.00,   -1.51
    ,   2.02,   -1.53
Sample 3,   3.01,      -2.52
    ,   3.00,   -2.51
Sample 4,   4.01,      -3.52
    ,   4.00,   -3.51
    ,   4.02,   -4.53
    ,   4.01,   -3.51
    ,   4.03,   -3.54
Sample 5,   5.01,      -4.52
    ,   5.00,   -4.51
    ,   5.02,   -4.53
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={Name, pH, concentration}, 
    fixed zerofill, 
    columns/Name/.style={string type,},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    every row no 3/.style={before row=\midrule},
    every row no 6/.style={before row=\midrule},
    every row no 8/.style={before row=\midrule},
    every row no 13/.style={before row=\midrule},
    ]{dataC.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this solution is a possibility. But I thought there should be a solution with less manual action. Main problem here if I  have to change the amount of rows of only one sample, I have to adjust all following `every row no`. I could accept this answer if it would be possible to use a counter as row number and increase it manually by `\addtocounter` but this is not possible in the optional argument of `pgfplotstypeset`. Do you have an idea how to solve this? At least for an idea I would be really thankful.